# Close workbook in excel with name changing weekly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file with the below macro. And basically I need it to close all the workbooks that opens however one of my files name changes everyweek so for example, for this week it is called Special Services 1503,next week it will be Special Services 1504 etc. Any idea on how to edit the below code so that I can close this file without manually editing the number in vba?

```
Workbooks("2014 Actuals").Close SaveChanges = True
Workbooks("Special Services Budget 2015").Close SaveChanges = True
```

The above work because no editing, the below works but I manually have to change week number from 1504 to 1505 etc every week.

```
Workbooks("Special Services 1504").Close SaveChanges = True
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Does the 1504 have anything to do with the current week (as in could you figure it out based on a date function?)

Comment: How about: `FileName = Dir$("Special Services Budget*.xls*")`?  By the way, how did you open it without knowing the name?

Comment: Hey the week is related to the previous week not the current week but the one before that you see. The file is always produced a week before current week.

Comment: In regards to how did I open it, i have another macro which opens and copies data from the files which I did not include in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as a separate answer because it's a completely different approach from the previous one:

*If and only if you are sure that only that workbook has a name which looks like **Special Services 1054**, then you can use the Like operator like this* :

```
For Each objWb In Workbooks
    If objWb.Name Like "Special Services *"
        objWb.Close SaveChanges = True
    End If
Next objWb
```

As stated in my previous answer, this approach is more reliable than the other one **but only if you are 100% sure that there might not be another workbook with a similar name opened**.

Comment: Matteo NNZ - for your second answer:        i am guessing that I will have to write the code down for the 52 weeks.   so for example " special servies 1504" etc

Comment: @Nwaaaa no, you don't have to write down the code for 52 weeks, it will always find the currently opened workbook with the name that looks like "Special services " something else and it will close it down. All you need is that code snippet.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying syntax error,  could you explain what the "*" stands for?  and do i need to amend the code any further ? i just copied and pasted to the vba code I already had.

Comment: @Nwaaaa The "*" means to look for any wb name that starts with "Special Services" and ends it doesnt matter how. There's no syntax error in the code above, you might have copied-pasted something wrong. Maybe you might want to add the code here so I can have a look.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the logic, you only need to build a dynamic index:

```
firstWeek2015 = 1500 '<-- starting seed
yearFactor = Year(Now()) - 2015 '<-- we take the current year and we subtract 2015: this year it will be 0, next year 1 etc.
weekFactor = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now()) '<--we just take the current week
newIndex = firstWeek2015 + yearFactor*52 + weekFactor
```

and replace it into your workbook name:

```
Workbooks("Special Services " & newIndex).Close SaveChanges = True
```

Even if I would rather:

```
1) Use the same logic that you used to open the file;
2) Use a RegEx-based solution (if "Special Services ????" is the only file of that kind).
```

Comment: I realised there was a bug in my previous "newIndex" generation, now it should be fine (see edited code).

Comment: Is there a way to instead of picking up this week, pick up last weeks date using the same code? For example this is the 5 th week in January but the file will now be called "special services 1504"

Comment: @Nwaaaa I don't think so, because for how you described your problem the date is not inside the code but only the name of the workbook. If I figured out your problem well, I just suggest you to use the solution below (this one is an algorithm to define the name, but if you're not sure about it I would rather go for the "Like *" solution.